# How to read perl data structures in external file using perl

Tags: perl, data-structures

I have a perl file containing some hash references (abc.pl) and i want to open this file in another perl file, so that i can convert it to json using Json XS. When i try to open abc.pl, perl reads it as text and i am unable to convert it into json.

So, i just wanted to know the way to read abc.pl in another perl file so that the hash references are read properly and then can be converted to json.

Comment: Hash references cannot exist in files. Please clarify. Do you mean it contains code that returns a hash reference?

Comment: the file contains combinations of data structures like these

abc{z}={ a=>"bc", d=>"ef", g=>[h=>{t=>"ij"}]};

Comment: I presume you mean `$abc{z}`, in which case it's Perl code. Make sure the file ends with `\%abc`, and you can use friedo's code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a data file that looks something like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'bar' => 2,
          'baz' => 3,
          'foo' => 1
        };
```

You can evaluate the structure using [do](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) function. For example,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;

my $data = do 'abc.pl';
my $json = encode_json $data;

print $json;
```

Comment: thanx this worked for this example...but what if the file contains many complex data structures like this

$VAR1{vr1} = {
          'bar' => 2,
          'baz' => 3,
          'foo' => 1
        };
$VAR1{vr2} = {
          'bar' => 2,
          'baz' => 3,
          'foo' => 1
        };

and so on

Comment: Then you'll probably want to split it somehow and use `eval` on the resulting strings.

Comment: splitting and using eval evaluates them as strings and doesnt convert it into json

Comment: `eval` will evaluate them. It's up to you to convert it to JSON once you have deserialized the reference. I've already shown you how to do that.